# python [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

I learn python on Ubuntu system. There were errors shen I tried to read a file .

```
fw = open(outfile,"a") 
outfile = 'sougou/Reduced/C000008_pre.txt'

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sougou/Reduced/C000008_pre.txt'
```

Comment: Either "sougou" does not exist or "sougou/Reduced" does not exist

Comment: Where are you calling Python script from? Or is this in an interactive terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Without any additional information, I can see two possibilities here.

1. The file you are trying to access doesn't exist.
2. The path to the file is not correct *relative to the location you are calling your Python script from.*

Try providing the absolute path to the file, and see if that fixes your issue:

```
outfile = '/some/path/here/sougou/Reduced/C000008_pre.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe file `sougou/Reduced/C000008_pre.txt` does not exist
2. The script does not be put in directory which contains `sougou` directory
3. You should close file after open: `fw.close()` or using `with open(outfile,"a") as fw:` is better